# Internals of array of strings vs. concatenated string in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to better understand internals of ElasticSearch, so I would like to know if there are any differences in how ElasticSearch internally computes term statistics for the following two cases.

The first case is when I have documents like:

```
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "bar": "long string"
    },
    {
      "bar": "another long string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Or a document like:

```
{
  "foobar": "long string another long string"
}
```

My understanding is that the first document gets flattened to:

```
{
  "foo.bar": ["long string", "another long string"]
}
```

So it seems the question is really, is the second and third documents indexed the same? Is term statistics computed the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question! If you index the first and the second document and then look at the [term vectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html) for the `foo.bar` field, you'll notice that frequencies and offsets are exactly the same, however, the positions differ.

[image: term vector differences]

The reason for this has to do with the [`position_increment_gap`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/position-increment-gap.html) setting, whose default value is 100. The reason this fake gap is introduced is to prevent phrase queries from matching across the values.

So in the first document, the `foo.bar` field has multiple values as you rightly noticed, hence why the term positions differ with the second document where there's only a single string.

```
["long string", "another long string"]
```

That means that if you try to use a `match_phrase` query for matching `string another`, then it won't match the first document, only the second one.

You can still decide to change the value of `position_increment_gap` in the mapping of the first document and set it to 0, in which case both document would be indexed exactly the same way.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know you can get out term vectors. Very useful. Thanks.